# How to Display Latest Weeks Volume by Default in Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I am looking for some help in displaying a set of numbers on my dashboard but I need to display the latest week whenever the dashboard is open but also allow the user to change the week that they are looking at through the filters.

My data is the following:

```
latest_week_rank | week_date | completed_orders

1 | 31/01/2020 | 3500
2 | 24/01/2020 | 6450
3 | 17/01/2020 | 6050
4 | 10/01/2020 | 6110
5 | 03/01/2020 | 4000
6 | 27/12/2019 | 3500
7 | 20/12/2019 | 7500
8 | 13/12/2019 | 7450
9 | 06/12/2019 | 7540
10 | 29/11/2019 | 6900
11 | 22/11/2019 | 7100
12 | 15/11/2019 | 7400
13 | 08/11/2019 | 7550
```

I am going to be using a Multi KPI Extension where I will display the volume of 3500 for the latest weeks volume in my data and then have a second measure to then display a % value to show if the volume is higher then previous week or lower.

so a formula: (3500 / 6450) giving me a % of 45.74% down

The tricky bit is how to do the expression/variable to show the default of the latest week but also having the ability to filter and pick another week which would then change the previous week if the selection of the week_date is changed.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could advise on how I could tackle this issue to display my data on my dashboard as I am fairly new to Qlik so just trying to get my head around how everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to write expression which gives me the latest weeks volume and also allows me to filter and view previous weeks data.

```
Sum({<week_date={">=$(=Weekstart(max(week_date)))<=$(=Weekend(max(week_date)))"}>}completed_orders)
```

In regards to the percentage I have used the same code and then taken the latest weeks and divided the previous weeks . To get the previous week all I did was add a `-1` to look at the previous week and then changed the option to show it as a %.

---

Code in the Data Tab:

```
set vvWeekOrders = Sum({<week_date={">=$(=Weekstart(max(week_date)))<=$(=Weekend(max(week_date)))"}>}completed_orders);
```

but this changes my values to 0, do i need to change the code if I am using set?

Comment: great so you can choose own answer as the best one :-) if you have anymore problems with qlikview/qliksense feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks Hubert, I did have a question. Rather than adding this into variables, I was also trying to see if I could add the code in the Data Tab as a Global variable but this doesn't work, any ideas why? Btw I have added my code by Editing the above.

Comment: what about master measure?

Comment: So create a measure from the field using the code I have? ok will have a look at that, thanks